# Custom Payment method BaseUrl issue not Defined issue. Magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout, payment-methods

I have custom payment method. On checkout when we select that Payment Method then it shows Pop-up to add card details and all these stuff but it is not working as expected now when I click on Checkout then it shows one error in Console you can see in image
[image]

while when I tried same thing if I tried on FireFox then it shows some other error which is I think more clear
[image]

saying config is not defined Now I dont know how to trace this issue any help would be really appreciated.
thanks